# Weird behavior with variable scope and 'require' in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I have 2 files:

**testrequire.js**

```
let a = {};

function foo() {
    a = 'test';
 };

module.exports.foo = foo;
module.exports.a = a;
```

**test.js**

```
let a = require('./testrequire');

a.foo();

console.log(a);
```

When I run `test.js`, this is the result:

```
{ foo: [Function: foo], a: {} }
```

But I **expect** it to be like this:

```
{ foo: [Fuction: foo], a: 'test' }
```

---

However, when I change **testrequire.js** like this:

```
let a = {};

function foo() {
    a.b = 'test';
};

module.exports.foo = foo;
module.exports.a = a;
```

The result is:

```
{ foo: [Function: foo], a: { b: 'test' } }
```

And it is perfectly like what I expected.

---

**The question here is:** Why function `foo()` can modify `a`'s properties while it cannot modify `a`?

**P/S:** I did try `var` instead of `let` and the result is still the same. So it is definitely not ES6 `let` fault.

Comment: You have defined `a` to be an object. Object contains key-value pair. So, try writing `a={b: 'test'}` in your first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pointer thing. It's the same in C/C++, Java etc. We've gotten so used to closures that we've sort of expect regular pointers to work the same. But pointers/references are simple indirections.

Let's walk through your code:

```
let a = {};
```

Create an object (`{}`) and point the variable `a` to that object.

```
function foo() {
    a = 'test';
};
```

Declare a function `foo()` that overwrites the value of `a` with a string. Now, if you remember your C/assembly then you'd remember that the value of a pointer is the address of the thing it points to. So the original value of `a` is not `{}` but the address to that object. When you overwrite `a` with a string that object still exist and can be garbage collected unless something else points to it.

```
module.exports.foo = foo;
module.exports.a = a;
```

Export two properties, 1. `foo` which points to a function and 2. `a` which points to the same object that `a` is pointing to. Remember, just like in C/Java this does not mean that `module.exports.a` points to `a` but that it points to `{}`. Now you have two variables pointing to the same object `{}`.

Now, when you do:

```
a.foo();
```

All you're doing is changing the enclosed variable `a` to point to a string instead of the original object. You haven't done anything to `a.a` at all. It's still pointing to `{}`.

---

### Workarounds

There are two ways to get what you want. First, the OO way. Don't create a closure for `a`, make it a regular object property:

```
function foo() {
  this.a = 'test';
};
module.exports.foo = foo;
module.exports.a = {};
```

This will work as expected because modules in node.js are proper singletons so they can be treated as regular objects.

The second way to do this to use a getter to get the enclosed `a`. Remember that closures only work with functions, not objects. So just assigning the variable to a property like you did results in a regular pointer operation not a closure. The workaround is this:

```
let a = {};

function foo() {
  a = 'test';
};
function getA() {
  return a; // this works because we've created a closure
}
module.exports.foo = foo;
module.exports.getA = getA;
```

Now you can do:

```
a.foo();
a.getA(); // should return 'test'
```

Answer (score 2):

`foo` *can* modify the variable `a` to point to something else.

But this has no effect on the object exported. When the `require` is done, the calling module receives whatever `a` pointed to at the time. After that, it does not care about what happens to (the variable) `a`.

In your second example, you are not assigning `a` to a new object, but you are modifying the existing object (by adding a new field). That will of course be visible to anyone who got hold of that object before.

This is (very roughly) analogous to

```
function callerDoesNotSeeThis(a){  a = 1 }

function callerSeesThis(a){  a.foo = 1 }
```